# iso 8601 Date Time format to hh:mm - Then add/subtract minutes

Tags: lua

I am attempting to take this date format **2021-09-28T12:00:00-05:00** and extract the hours and minutes. For my use, the actual day and timezone are not relevant. One easy way I have gone about this is getting the substring.

```
starDate = "2021-09-28T12:00:00-05:00"
print(string.sub(starDate, 12, 16))
```

I have accomplished this in the past by splitting the hour and minute out as separate strings and adding/subtracting from the hour and minute then joining the two together later.  Forgive my rookie code..

```
function OpenMath()
  TriggerMath1 = math.floor(TOS / 60)
  TriggerMath2 = string.format('%d \n' , TOS - TriggerMath1 * 60, '' )
  print(TriggerMath2)
  if OpenM < TriggerMath2 then
    TH = OpenH - (TriggerMath1 + 1)
    TM = OpenM + (60 - TriggerMath2)
   else
    TH = OpenH - TriggerMath1
    TM = OpenM - TriggerMath2
  end
  if TM == 60 then
    TH = TH + 1
    TM = '00'
  end
  TH = string.format('%02d' , TH, '' )
  TM = string.format('%02d' , TM, '' )
  print('OpenMath')
end
```

Is there a better way to extract the hh:mm as a time, then add or subtract the minutes from the time?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Lua's facilities for working with dates and times are pretty minimal, but in this circumstance, where you have a nice consistent input format and don't care about time zones, we can actually get the job done just using what's in the standard library.

```
function stardateToDatetime(stardate)
  local Y,M,D,h,m,s = stardate:match('^(%d%d%d%d)-(%d%d)-(%d%d)T(%d%d):(%d%d):(%d%d)')
  return {
    year = tonumber(Y, 10);
    month = tonumber(M, 10);
    day = tonumber(D, 10);
    hour = tonumber(h, 10);
    min = tonumber(m, 10);
    sec = tonumber(s, 10);
  }
end
local dt = stardateToDatetime("2021-09-28T12:00:00-05:00")
print(os.date(nil, os.time(dt))) -- "Tue Sep 28 12:00:00 2021"
```

The field names are not arbitrary, but are taken from the documentation for [os.date](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.date), which means you can pass the table to `os.time()` to get a system timestamp, and do math on the date/time represented by adjusting the fields. It's ok if you put them out of range, because `os.time` will correct for that (converting, e.g., `hour=1;min=120` to `hour=3;min=0`):

```
dt.min = dt.min + 135 -- 2h15m
print(os.date(nil, os.time(dt))) -- "Tue Sep 28 14:15:00 2021"
```

If you need the table normalized, you can feed it to `os.time()` to get a system timestamp back and then pass that through `os.date()` to get a normalized table:

```
print(dt.hour, dt.min) -- 12 135
local normalized = os.date('*t', os.time(dt))
print(normalized.hour, normalized.min) -- 14 15
```

For more details, see:

- [os.date](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.date) -- convert system timestamp to table or human-readable string
- [os.time](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.time) -- get system timestamp from system clock or datetime table
- [string.match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match) -- regex-like string matching and subgroup extraction